# Splitting characters

Tags: java, android, html

My characters is "`!`,`;`,`%`,`@`,`**`,`**`,`(`,`)`" which get from XML. when I split it with '`,`', I lost the '`,`'.

How can I do to avoid it.
I have already tried to change the comma to '&#002C', but it does not work.

Thre result I want is "`!`,`;`,`%`,`@`,`,`,`(`,`)`", but not "`!`,`;`,`%`,`@`,,`(`,`)`"

Comment: If you want individual characters, `String.toCharArray()` would do the job .

Comment: I just want to split it with ',', because there are some characters more than one character.

Comment: *"There are some characters more than one character"* — That sentence seems to contradict itself. Define "character". Do you mean: "Some characters consists of multiple bytes?

Comment: The result I want is [!, ;, %, @, ,, (, )]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String::split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) use regex so you can split with this regex [`((?<!,),|,(?!,))`](https://regex101.com/r/fKb0tg/1) like this :

```
String string = "!,;,%,@,,,(,)";
String[] split = string.split("((?<!,),|,(?!,))");
```

Details

- `(?<!,),` match a comma if not preceded by a comma
- `|` or
- `,(?!,)` match a comma if not followed by a comma

---

Outputs

```
!
;
%
@
,
(
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to extract all characters from string, you can do so by using `String.toCharArray()`[1] :

```
String str = "sample string here";
char[] char_array = s.toCharArray();
```

If you just want to iterate over the characters in the string, you can use the character array obtained from above method or do so by using a for loop and `str.charAt(i)`[2] to access the character at position i.

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()
[2]https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)

Comment: some of the characters may be like"I, am, a, boy,, .". So, how do I keep the first ',' after 'boy'

Comment: Read [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) .

Answer (score 0):

try this, this could be help full. First I replaced the '**,**' with other string and do split. After complete other string replace with ','

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "!,;,%,@,**,**,(,)";
    System.out.println(str);
    str = str.replace("**,**","**/!/**");
    String[] array = str.split(",");
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(array).map(s -> s.replace("**/!/**", ",")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  }
```

out put

```
 !,;,%,@,**,**,(,)
 [!, ;, %, @, ,, (, )]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to define when the comma is an actual delimiter, and when it is part of a character sequence.

We need to assume that a sequence of commas surrounded by commas is an actual character sequence we want to capture. It can be done with lookarounds:

```
String s = "!,;,,,%,@,**,**,,,,(,)";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s.split(",(?!,)|(?<!,),"));
```

This regular expression splits by a comma that is either preceded by something that is not a comma, or followed by something that is not a comma.

---

Note that your formatting string, that is, every character sequence separated by a comma, is a **bad design**, since you require both the possibility to use a comma as sequence, and the possibility to use multiple characters to be used. That means you can combine them too!

What, for example, if I want to use these two character sequences:

- `,`
- `,,,,`

Then I construct the formatting string like this: `,,,,,,`. It is now unclear whether `,` and `,,,,` should be character sequences, or `,,` and `,,,`.